# One persistent library between iTunes (Win) and Ubuntu where playcounts in Ubuntu update in iTunes?

Tags: ubuntu, itunes, mp3-player

**One machine**, dual booted with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, sharing a storage disk where the music is located.
All my playlists are based off `date added` and `play count`
Is it possible to have plays in Ubuntu (using Banshee, Rythmbox or whatever) update the iTunes library?

Basically is there an Ubuntu player that can read the iTunes library file and keep it updated?

Comment: would you be open to using wine?

Comment: I'd prefer not to, has given me headaches in the past and I've gone through a lot of trouble getting the dual boot system working correctly so using wine with my nice fresh windows install only a partition away seems like a step in the wrong direction!  But it may be the only option for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have plays in Ubuntu (using Banshee, Rythmbox or
>   whatever) update the iTunes library?

Unfortunately **NO**.

iTunes is not available for Linux (You know this). You can use it via [playonlinux app](http://www.playonlinux.com/en). 
To install iTunes than do this:

1. Open the terminal(CTRL+ALT+T) and run following command to install playonlinux. `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`
2. Open playonlinux and Click on install. You will see bunch of application based on category including most popular program, most downloaded, most rated. Type iTunes in the searchbar and you will find the several version of iTunes. [image: 1]
3. Select the version that you want to install. [image: 2]
4. You will be informed with version that you are installing and the location of your installation with some warning Click on next to proceed. [image: 3]
5. PlayonLinux now download the iTunes or ask for the source depending upon the version you have choosen. 

   [image: 4]
6. You can finally see installation widget for iTunes Click on Next and follow the procedure like installing simple application in windows.
7. After following all procedure iTunes will be install in your system.

**Note: PlayonLinux has some issue (just some I tested it myself)  with iTunes 10. Therefore you can install iTunes 7. You can  use wine to install version 10. But the performance isn’t satisfactory like version 7.**

This should solve the problem, just use iTunes to play the music.

**[SOURCE](http://freshtutorial.com/install-itunes-ubuntu-linux/)**

Comment: Do you know if there will be any compatibility issues with using the same library file between iTunes 10 and 7? iTunes 7 is 6yrs old! If there was a non-wine solution I'd be a lot happier but I'll try this over the weekend and if it successfully keeps my library file updated I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: There may or may not be compatibility issues with the file as the Basic structure of the file has not changed (as far as I know). Also you can use iTunes 10 also (I know it have some minor issues but they are nothing major).

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about having the proper playcounts, you might be satisfied with a thirdparty tool like [last.fm](http://last.fm). You can use different apps to listen to your music, and the last.fm plugin will keep track your playcounts.